# How can I match the \0 character in a regex in C++?

Tags: c++, regex

I need to match the text '\0' with the same regex that I would match 'a' or 'b'.  (a regex for a character constant in C++).  I've tried a bunch of different regexes, but haven't gotten a successful one yet.  My latest attempt:

```
^['].|\\0[']
```

Most of the other things I've tried have given seg faults, so this is really the closest I've gotten.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Why do you need to match it? `\0` is the [null terminator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) so it really isn't part of the string, and finding it is trivial.

Comment: g++  I'm also using the "regex.h" package

Comment: I'm officially interested in *why* one would do this. An actual *example* a **real string** you want to match with such a thing would probably be very telling, in more ways than one.

Comment: It's for an assignment, we're creating a language translator and one of the things we need is to test the null terminator as a character constant.  I'm officially interested why my professor thinks this is a necessary piece of the language, but he does..

Comment: Then you're not looking for a null-terminator in the string your parsing; you're looking for an escaped zero in char-form. i.e. `\\ ` followed by `0`.

Comment: right, but I'm still unable to match that with a regex...

Comment: Your updated question is much better. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I think I put the incorrect slashes

Comment: Does *that* do what you want: `^(['](.|\\0)['])` (still not sure I'm on the same page you're looking for). Or even `^('(.|\\0)')` seems like it would do what you want, assuming you want a full capture of the two single quotes and the thing inside (a single char or a backhack-zero).

Comment: You don't want to capture the quotes?

Comment: @Rapptz I do want to capture the single quotes

Comment: @WhozCraig I've tried both of those, they don't work with the makeRegex and matchRegex that I'm using (although they do work on a regex matcher that I've tried online).  I'm using the C++ header file <regex.h>

Comment: C++ doesn't have `<regex.h>`.

Comment: In one of the earlier comments you said you are using GCC? C++11 regex support is extremely rudimentary there. You won't be able to use it for any serious matching.

Comment: Ok, if you're using `regcomp()` with REG_EXTENDED, I *think* this will do it for you: `^('(.|([\\]0))')`. Let me know.

Comment: Followup, in case you're still watching: [see it live](http://ideone.com/TEQaeC).

Comment: @Rapptz sorry, it's the C library then.

Comment: @WhozCraig that last comment worked, thanks a ton for that help!  I was beginning to think I'd never find a solution

Answer (score 1):

This works pretty nicely with what I've tested ('a','b','\0').

If you don't have `std::regex` or `boost::regex` I guess what you can get out of it is the fact that the regex I used is `('.'|'\\0')`.

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    strings.push_back(R"('a')");
    strings.push_back(R"('b')");
    strings.push_back(R"('\0')");
    boost::regex rgx(R"(('.'|'\\0'))");
    boost::smatch match;
    for(auto& i : strings) {
        if(boost::regex_match(i,match, rgx)) {
            boost::ssub_match submatch = match[1];
            std::cout << submatch.str() << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

[Example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4uto2i%242)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing magic about `'\0'`; it's just a character, like any other character, and there's nothing (almost) special you have to do to use it in a regular expression. The only problem you might run into is if you use it in the middle of a character literal that you pass to a function that treats it as the end of a string. To avoid that, force it into a `std::string`:

```
const char s[] = "a\0b";
std::string not_my_str(s); // not_my_str holds "a"
std::string str(s, 3);     // str holds "a\0b"
```

Once you've constructed the string object, the embedded `'\0'` gets no special treatment. Except, of course, if you copy the contents with a function that treats it specially.

Answer (score 0):

The regex that works (in this instance, using the C header ) is:

```
^('(.|([\\]0))')
```

Thanks to @WhozCraig for the help!