# Is \0 ("\\0" in a C-style regex string) a valid escape sequence in C++ regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, c++, regex, c++11, ecma262

**NOTE**: When I say *the regex `[\0]`* I mean the regex `[\0]` (not contained in a C-style string, which would then be `"[\\0]"`). If I haven't put quotes around it, it's not a C-style string, and the backslashes shouldn't be interpreted as escaping a C-style string.

Inspired by [this question and my investigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483411/c11-regex-multiline-why-does-the-group-0-nsome-text-have-everything#comment36010658_23483411), I tried the following code in clang 3.4:

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string input = "foobar";
    std::regex regex("[^\\0]*"); // Note, this is "\\0", not "\0"!

    return std::regex_match(input, regex);
}
```

Apparently, clang doesn't like this, as it throws:

> `std::__1::regex_error`: The expression contained an invalid escaped character, or a trailing escape.

It seems to be the `[^\0]` part (changing it to `[^\n]` or something similar works fine). It seems to be an invalid escape character. I want to clarify that I'm not talking about the `'\0'` character (null-character) or `'\n'` character (newline character). **In C-style strings, what I'm talking about is `"\\0"`** (a string containing backslash zero) **and `"\\n"`** (a string containing backslash n). `"\\n"` seems to get transformed into `"\n"` by the regex engine, but it chokes on `"\\0"`.

The C++11 standard says in section 28.13 [re.grammar] that:

> The regular expression grammar recognized by `basic_regex` objects constructed with the ECMAScript flag is that specified by ECMA-262, except as specified below.

I'm no expert on ECMA-262, but [I tried the regular expression on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WJyfB/1/) and it's working fine there in JavaScript land.

So now I'm wondering if the regex `[^\0]` is valid in ECMA-262 and the C++11 standard removed support for it (in the stuff following `... except as specified below.`).

**Question**: Is the `\0` (not the null-character; in a string literal this would be `"\\0"`) escape sequence legal in a C++11 regular expression? Is it legal in ECMA-262 (or are browser JS VMs just being "too" lenient)? What's the cause/justification for the different behaviors?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194513/how-can-i-match-the-0-character-in-a-regex-in-c

Comment: @user3590396: Sure, I could just write `"[^" + std::string(1, '\0') + "]*"` and be done with it, but I'm not asking *how* to match this, I'm asking *why* there's a difference, given that C++11 regexes are based on ECMA's regexes.

Comment: I think it's because ECMA regexes use a higher order of string and will escape \0 when it is typed into a string instead of compiling it down to a string termination character, whereas in c strings it terminates the string, which is why you need to do some legwork to interpolate it.

Comment: @MikeH-R: But I'm not using the character `'\0'`. I'm using the backslash character followed by the zero character (in a C-style string, this is `"\\0"`). `"\\n"` works, but `"\\0"` doesn't work. Maybe I'm not understanding you.

Comment: Good point, sorry I misread the regex and was thinking it was `"\0"` in the middle, please ignore :(

Comment: @MikeH-R: Well I'll admit it's kind of confusing. I edited the question to try to make it clearer.

Comment: Just to note, libstdc++ 4.9.0 does accept this code and does not report a warning. This may be a bug in libc++.

Comment: @sharth: thanks for testing with libstdc++ 4.9.0. A bug seems likely, to me.

Comment: @Cornstalks: I've pushed it to the llvm bug tracker (I personally believe that gnu's behavior is correct). http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19678

Comment: [^\\0] is "not backslash nor 0" and not "not backslash 0". It's not clear if you intend not to match char with value 0, or the special escaping regular expression "match all" capture. If you intend the former, then you can write "[^0\\\]" it's semantically equivalent.

Comment: Fixed in libc++ revision 209307

Comment: @sharth: I want to give you credit for pointing out this seems like an issue and filing a bug report, so if you post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Cornstalks: Sure, although Marshall did the actual work by putting together the patch and understanding how the `<regex>` code is implemented. Also, I think you meant for your last comment to go  xryl669.

Comment: @sharth: Shoot, you're totally right about that last comment!

Comment: @xryl669: I'm not talking about the regex `[^\\0]`. I'm talking about the regex `[^\0]` (in a literal C-style string, that would be `"[^\\0]"`). I'm talking about the ECMA 262 regex escape sequence for the NUL character (again, not the C/C++ literal string escape sequence for the NUL character). It kinda sucks how much confusion this seems to be causing, but I'm not sure how to say it any clearer/better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in libc++'s implementation of `<regex>`. It should be fixed now in the trunk, and this should propagate to OS X's release code eventually.

- [Bug Report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19678)
- [Patch](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=209307)

Also, here is the excerpt from the ECMA 262 Standard that is the basis for this bug report:

> 15.10.2.11 DecimalEscape
>
> The production `DecimalEscape :: DecimalIntegerLiteral [lookahead ∉ DecimalDigit]` evaluates as follows:
>
> 1. Let i be the MV of DecimalIntegerLiteral.
> 2. If i is zero, return the EscapeValue consisting of a <NUL> character (Unicode value 0000).
> 3. Return the EscapeValue consisting of the integer i.
>
> Note: ... \0 represents the <NUL> character and cannot be followed by a decimal digit.